# Django foreign key reverse set count

Tags: python, django, django-models

So, provided code like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length)
```

I might have a relationship like this: category_two's parent is category_one and category_three's parent is category two.

I want to filter out all the category that doesn't have children. this means like this:

```
category_three.category_set.count() == 0; # category_three has no children
category_two.category_set.count() != 0; # category_three's parent is category_two
```

But When I try this:

```
Category.objects.filter(category_set__count=0) # this is the wrong code that won't work
# this would actually gives out the following error message
#Cannot resolve keyword 'category_set' into field. Choices are: category, id, name, parent, parent_id
```

Basically what I want is filter out all the ending category, means the category that won't have any child.

Hope that I explained clearly. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `__isnull` lookup:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(category__isnull=True)
```

In the context of a relationship, `__isnull=True` matches if there are no related objects, and `__isnull=False` matches if there is at least one related object. Alternatively, you can replace `category__isnull=True` with `category=None`, this will generate the same query.

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'category_set' into field. Choices are: category, id, name, parent, parent_id

Comment: @castiel Dammit, got it wrong again. The filter should be `category__isnull`, not `category_set`. Guess I'll never learn it as I always use `related_name`...

Comment: Thanks bro,this is exact the way I want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

Try filtering on an annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count

categories = Category.objects.annotate(num_children=Count('category_set')).filter(num_children__gt=0)
```

Annotating every category with a field of 'num_children' which is the count of the 'category_set' field and then filtering should get you only the categories that have children.